# Whitespace remover for rails ERB templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whitespace, erb, tidy

after googling around with no success i try it here. i'm looking for a rails gem, which removes whitespace from rendered ERB templates, so code structure etc. gets removed, just compressed html code. any tip here?

thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you know about closing `<% -%>` tags. But removing *all* whitespace is potentially risky as different browsers do different things with whitespace, under different circumstances. You could probably put something into rack, but... wouldn't gzipping the entire response be a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in this, a Rack middleware which cleans text/html markup by automatically indenting and reformatting content:

http://coderack.org/users/webficient/middlewares/38-racktidy